# Send authtoken in ajax headers to Codeigniter REST API

Tags: php, api, rest, codeigniter

I have a Codeigniter App with REST API Controller and have tested in postman, it works well sending "authtoken" in headers. Now I'm trying to connect to the same method via ajax and API response is "Token not valid". I can see the request headers is not sending the authtoken.
I have tried sending as headers ( headers: {"authtoken": authtoken}, ) and sending beforeSend, and don't work.

My PHP Code:

```
public function __construct() {
    
     parent::__construct();
    
     $this->load->model('Api_model');
}

 public function data_post()
{
   
     
   $email = $this->input->post('username', TRUE);
   $password = $this->input->post('password', TRUE);
    if (trim($email)=='' || trim($password)=='')
    {
        // form validation error
        $message = array(
            'status' => FALSE,
            'error' => 'Error',
            'message' => 'Please fill username and password'
        );
        $this->response($message, REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }else
    {
        $user = $this->Api_model->login($email, $password);
        if($user){
             $this->response($user, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);  
        }else{
            
              $this->response([
                    'status' => FALSE,
                    'message' => 'Username or Password are incorrect'
              ], REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);  
        }
        
    }
}
```

My Javascript Code:

```
var authtoken = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9..........";
$.ajax({
    url: 'app_url_here/api' + "/" + action,
    data: {
        username: username,
        password: password
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
        var xhr = settings.xhr();
        xhr.open(this.method, this.url, true);
         xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        xhr.setRequestHeader("authtoken", authtoken)

    },
    complete: function (data) {

    },

    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data, status, xhr) { console.log(status); console.log(xhr); }
});
```

Request Headers:

```
Accept
    */*
Accept-Encoding
    gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language
    es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Connection
    keep-alive
Cookie
    _ c3bcfce89cdf..........
Host
    my_url_origin.com
Referer
    https://my_url_origin
User-Agent
    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0
```

Comment: You shouldn’t use the username + password for this. Use an OAuth 2.0 system, where the user is redirected to your site to login which then returns a bearer (resource token) to the site which can then access the endpoint if its a valid request based on the scope the user allowed the person to do... you’re not giving your users much security allowing 3rd party applications to control the username and password fields

Comment: This is not the final use of this, I am testing in browser now but it will be for a cordova app. Not the same Scenario but will use ajax too. Every user will have an extra token.

Comment: I changed jsonp for json (jsonp does not support custom headers). Then error is for cors, Added 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' to Controller but still get "Token is not defined".